# Extracting lowest complex number from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

The vector is taking points to a rectangle. I want to be able to take the lowest and highest complex number and assigne it to 2 different complex numbers. I've only tried for the lowest with the below but it doesnt seem to find the lowest and just return the 1st element.

```
vector < complex<double>* > xs;
typedef typename vector < complex<double>* >::iterator Iter;
xs.push_back(&pointa); 
xs.push_back(&pointb); 
xs.push_back(&pointc); 
xs.push_back(&pointd); 

for (Iter p = xs.begin(); p != xs.end(); ++p)
{
   if((*p)->real()<(*p+1)->real() && (*p)->imag()<(*p+1)->imag())
   {
      double a = (*p)->real();
      double b = (*p)->imag();
      complex <double> botleft_1(a,b);
   }
   else
   {
   }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about formatting your code?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "lowest complex number". How do you wish to compare two complex numbers? |u| < |v|?

Comment: To be mathematically correct, there's no such thing as lowest complex number (they are not comparable). What exactly are you looking for? Maybe what you want is the number with the lowest modulus?

Answer (score 4):

The immediate bug in your code is that `*p+1` means `(*p)+1`.

The next bug after you fix that to `*(p+1)` will be that you go one element off the end of the vector. You should be comparing each value with the lowest/highest so far, not with the next value in the vector.

There is in any case no such thing as the "lowest" or "highest" complex number - the complex numbers are not an ordered field (theorem). You can define any comparison operator you like on complex numbers, but it will be pretty arbitrary, for example it won't necessarily have ordered field properties such as `a < b && c < d => a+c < b+d`. The comparison you have defined does have that property, but is not a strict weak order, so it might not behave the way you expect once you start doing comparisons among 3 or more values.

For example, consider the values `complex<double> a(1,1), b(0,3), c(2,2);`, and the comparison function `lt(complex<double> lhs, complex<double> rhs) { return lhs.real() < rhs.real() && lhs.imag() < rhs.imag(); }`.

Then `lt(a,b)` and `lt(b,a)` are both false. This means `a` and `b` are equivalent as far as the ordering is concerned.

Likewise, `lt(b,c)` and `lt(c,b)` are both false. This means `b` and `c` are equivalent as far as the ordering is concerned.

However, `lt(a,c)` is true. This means `a` and `c` are not equivalent as far as the ordering is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you do not compare with the lowest number, only with next number. Try something like this:

```
complex<double> *lowest = *xs.begin();
for (Iter p = xs.begin() + 1; p != xs.end(); ++p){
    if ((*p)->real() < lowest->real() && (*p)->imag() < lowest->imag())
        lowest = *p;
}
```

After the loop, the variable `lowest` will have be the one you want.

Also, in your version of the loop, you compare to `p + 1` which will be `xs.end()` on the last item, and that will not be a valid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [boost::minmax_element](http://www.boost.org/libs/algorithm/minmax/index.html)

```
std::pair< Iter > pairit = boost::minmax_element( xs.begin(), xs.end(), 
    [&]( complex<double>* pcomplexA, complex<double>* pcomplexB ) {
         //  Suitable comparison predicate (see Steve Jessop's answer)
         return pcomplexA->abs() < pcomplexB->abs(); // |a| < |b|
    });
```